# Iterate over a pages with geb/selenium

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

I want to iterate over a list of pages verifying the contents of each page

With GEB I would like to iterate over eg. `https://github.com/trending`
then visit every page in trending and verify the title and then proceed with the next page.

However the Error `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` is bothering me.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('org.gebish:geb-core:3.3'),
    @Grab('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.141.59'),
    @Grab('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.141.59'),
    @GrabExclude('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.9')])
import geb.Browser
import geb.navigator.Navigator
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

import geb.Page

import static geb.Browser.drive

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/v/Downloads/chromedriver")
def chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver()
println chromeDriver.getSessionId()
drive(driver: chromeDriver, baseUrl: "https://github.com") { 
    to ProviderListPage
    Navigator pages = list()
    pages.each {
        to ProviderPage, it.attr("href").split('/').reverse()[1],it.attr("href").split('/').reverse()[0]
        waitFor { 5 }
        driver.navigate().back()
    }
    driver.quit()
}

class ProviderListPage extends Page {
    static url = "/trending"

    static content = {
        providers { $(".h3 a") }
    }
    def list() {
        return providers
    }

}
class ProviderPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        heading { $(".h3 a").text() }
    }
    def waitForHeading() {
        waitFor { assert $(".h3 a") }
    }
}
```

This is my example for everyone to reproduce. Only change `webdriver.chrome.driver`.

I do understand that the pages changes from `ListPage` to `ProviderPage #1` and causes the error:`StaleElementReferenceException`. But it is not clear to me is how am I able to navigate back and forth between pages and go over my list of page eg. `ProviderPage #2`

Comment: How about sharing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. complete test & page classes? How can anyone know which element you get a `StaleElementReferenceException` for? Make your problem reproducible, please.

Comment: Next time please notify me with a comment after updating your question. I just noticed by chance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

- From the overview page you navigate to another page, then use "browser back", i.e. the overview page is loaded again (even though maybe from the browser cache).
- But still you are referring to navigators from the first time the overview page was loaded, iterating over them via `each`. This means the elements are stale already.

Instead you should get all the information you need for iterating over the list the first time you open the overview page. This would also save time and make "browser back" completely superfluous. This works for me:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59958656

import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class GitHubTrendingIT extends GebReportingSpec {
  def test() {
    given:
    browser.baseUrl = "https://github.com"
    def providerListPage = to ProviderListPage
    report "provider list page"
    providerListPage
      .list()
      .collect {
        def pageInfo = it.attr("href").split('/').reverse()
        [pageInfo[1], pageInfo[0]]
      }
      .each {
        println "trending page = $it"
        to ProviderPage, it[0], it[1]
        report "trending page"
      }

    expect:
    true
  }
}
```

I wrapped the code into a Groovy test class. Just delete the parts you do not need if you want to execute the code from a script (I never do that).

BTW, the test prints the following at the time of writing this:

```
trending page = [wuhan2020, WebApp]
trending page = [oldboyxx, jira_clone]
trending page = [wuhan2020, wuhan2020]
trending page = [microsoft, ApplicationInspector]
trending page = [wuhan2020, api-server]
trending page = [lispczz, pneumonia]
trending page = [sundowndev, hacker-roadmap]
trending page = [binhnguyennus, awesome-scalability]
trending page = [puppeteer, puppeteer]
trending page = [nicrusso7, rex-gym]
trending page = [smicallef, spiderfoot]
trending page = [willmcgugan, rich]
trending page = [SwiftDocOrg, swift-doc]
trending page = [outflanknl, Scripts]
trending page = [globalcitizen, 2019-wuhan-coronavirus-data]
trending page = [sam-hosseini, freelancing-in-finland]
trending page = [hzwer, shareOI]
trending page = [sebastianruder, NLP-progress]
trending page = [giswqs, earthengine-py-notebooks]
trending page = [aamini, introtodeeplearning]
trending page = [Kethku, neovide]
trending page = [redcanaryco, atomic-red-team]
trending page = [baowenbo, DAIN]
trending page = [joeycastillo, The-Open-Book]
trending page = [meik97, XSpotify]
```